# NSUndoManager and GLKit

Tags: iphone, ios, struct, glkit, nsundomanager

I'm trying to support undo/redo in an iOS app that uses [GLKit](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GLkit/Reference/GLKit_Collection/_index.html).

When I try the following:

```
GLKVector3 currentTranslation = _panningObject.translation;
[[self.undoManager prepareWithInvocationTarget:_panningObject] setTranslation:currentTranslation];
```

I get a crash:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[NSMethodSignature signatureWithObjCTypes:]: unsupported type encoding spec '(' in '4(_GLKVector3={?=fff}{?=fff}{?=fff}[3f])8''
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Went ahead and made a bug report: Bug ID# 14794394. Sample project is available here: http://files.thermoglobalnuclearwar.com/GLKitBugs.zip

Comment: What's `_panningObject`? You might want to provide just *a wee bit* more information..

Comment: It's an object with a translation property of type GLKVector3

Comment: An Objective-C object derived from `NSObject`..?

Comment: Yep, thats the one :)

Comment: Ok - I suppose changing the `setTranslation:` method to use an Obj-C wrapper would work. It does appear to expect the `GLKVector3` struct to be a proper Obj-C object.

Comment: See the links to the Tweets in my answer. Explains the problem.

Comment: The core of this issue is that `NSMethodSignature`'s `+signatureWithObjCTypes:` method doesn't support union types.  More info at http://lists.apple.com/archives/cocoa-dev/2013/Sep/msg00107.html

Answer (score 0):

Still got no idea why GLKVector3 won't play nice, but I'm using this as a workaround:

```
- (void)setObject:(DrawableObject *)object translationX:(CGFloat)x y:(CGFloat)y z:(CGFloat)z {

    GLKVector3 translation = GLKVector3Make(x, y, z);
    GLKVector3 currentTranslation = object.translation;
    [[self.undoManager prepareWithInvocationTarget:self] setObject:object
                                                      translationX:currentTranslation.x y:currentTranslation.y z:currentTranslation.z];

    [object setTranslation:translation];
}
```

**EDIT:**

https://twitter.com/bddckr/status/370144778090192896
https://twitter.com/bddckr/status/370145021804425216